# AutoMapper strange IQueryable projection exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper

To skip pain, go to **EDIT** below.

---

I'm using EF with AutoMapper IQueryableExtensions.

Two of my models are as follows:

```
public class Article
{
    public int Key { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset Created { get; set; }

    public int? SemesterKey { get; set; }
    public virtual Semester Semester { get; set; }
}

public class Semester
{
    public int Key { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }

    // Other relationships
    public virtual ICollection<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AppUser> Users { get; set; }
}
```

And I have the following DTOs:

```
public class ArticleDto
{
    public int Key { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset Created { get; set; }

    // If I remove this (or ignore it), everything works.
    public SemesterDto Semester { get; set; }
}

public class SemesterDto
{
    public int Key { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Configuration:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Semester, SemesterDto>().MaxDepth(1);
Mapper.CreateMap<Article, ArticleDto>().MaxDepth(1);
```

The query:

```
context.Articles.Include(a => a.Semester)
                .OrderByDescending(a => a.Created)
                .Take(5)
                .ProjectTo<ArticleDto>()
                .ToList();
```

Executing the query yields the following strange exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: Property 'NS.Models.Semester Semester' is not defined for type 'NS.Models.Semester'
```

This is some of the stack trace:

```
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(Expression expression, PropertyInfo property)
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.MakeMemberAccess(Expression expression, MemberInfo member)
....
AutoMapper.MappingEngine.CreateMapExpression(ExpressionRequest request, Expression instanceParameter, IDictionary`2 typePairCount)
```

It seems as if AutoMapper generated an expression that is looking for a `Semester` property (in response to `ArticleDto.Semester` it seems) on the `NS.Models.Semester` type which of course doesn't exist.
I can get it working if I do the following:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Article, ArticleDto>().MaxDepth(1)
      .ForMember(a => a.Semester, c => c.MapFrom(a => a.Semester == null ? null : new SemesterDto() {
                        Key = a.Semester.Key,
                        Year = a.Semester.Year }));
```

But this is just the thing I'm trying to avoid writing by using AutoMapper!

It's probably something wrong on my side but I can't find anything suspicious.

## **EDIT:**

I have the following ctors on SemesterDto:

```
public SemesterDto()
{
}

public SemesterDto(int key, string name)
{
    Key = key;
    Name = name;
}
```

When I remove the second one everything works. Seems this is it, this is really strange behavior though. I never thought the ctor would make a problem so I didn't include it for clarity, everything is possible isn't it. Sorry about that.

So, is this a bug from AutoMapper or is there something else I misunderstood?

## **EDIT 2:**

Stripping this more, I tried mapping a `Semester` to `SemesterDto` directly and this is the result:

```
context.Semesters.ProjectTo<SemesterDto>().FirstOrDefault();
```

`NotSupportedException: Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.`

This strengthens the idea that the ctor is causing strange behavior.

Comment: What version are you using of AutoMapper?

Comment: Does `Project().To<ArticleDto>()` work properly?

Comment: Same result, same thing.

Comment: I can't repro this. Maybe you should show more details so we might see a gotcha you overlooked yourself.

Comment: I made some lightweight models just for testing and the mapping worked. Right now I'm trying to rule out the difference that made this fail.

Comment: @GertArnold please check the edit.

Comment: Constructor of `SemesterDto`? (It says `Semester`).

Comment: @GertArnold if you're talking about the ctor snippet in my edit, it was a typo. If you're talking about the exception, that it's saying `Semester`, strangely enough that's what it's saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been confirmed as a bug, see [this github issue](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/909). For now, I guess I'll just avoid ctors in my DTOs until the [promised](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/909#issuecomment-144707432) next release.

If you have `v4.1.0` or above, then this should've been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce the issue in your second edit. Somehow (I don't know AutoMapper well enough to see why), the parametrized constructor always takes precedence over the parameterless one in AutoMapper. And EF doesn't support parametrized constructors in its expression tree.

Anyway, you can fix this issue by using `ConstructProjectionUsing`:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Semester, SemesterDto>().MaxDepth(1)
      .ConstructProjectionUsing(sem => new SemesterDto());
```

Comment: **So** close! This works when mapping to a SemesterDto directly, but fails when SemesterDto is nested inside another dto just like before but with different exception: `System.InvalidOperationException: When called from 'VisitLambda', rewriting a node of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression' must return a non-null value of the same type. Alternatively, override 'VisitLambda' and change it to not visit children of this type.` I think you got us closest to the source of the problem so I already upvoted.

Comment: Hmm, for me it's OK with direct and nested projections.

Comment: So I discovered that this exception is actually being caused by using `ConstructProjectionUsing`. When I removed all ctors but kept using `ConstructProjectionUsing` the same exception occured (the `VisitLambda` exception)

Comment: There must be something in your code that doesn't play nice with AutoMapper. For me `ConstructProjectionUsing` works OK, also without parametrized ctors. I'm a bit stumped now.

Comment: I'm really confused now, I tried with a very simple model. As always, direct mapping works but mapping to a dto with a nested dto fails. I think for now I'll just avoid ctors on my DTOs with automapper for the rest of my life.

Answer (score 0):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Article, Dto.Article>()
      .ForMember(d => d.Semester, o => o.MapFrom(s => Mapper.Map<Dto.Semester>(s));
```

You need to tell it to use the `Semester` -> `Dto.Semester` mapping.

Comment: This instead gives me the following exception: `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'NS.Models.SemesterDto Map[Semester](System.Object)' method...`

Comment: How are you calling the initial mapper?

Comment: Which do you mean? On another note, I tried this: `.ForMember(a => a.Semester, c => c.MapFrom(a => Mapper.Map<SemesterDto>(a.Semester)));`.

Comment: This solution most probably works only for in memory mappings. I made some lightweight models and the same exception occurred.